# pstricks image is cut to a4 in landscape mode

Tags: xetex, pstricks, ubuntu, linux, paper-size

I am trying to create a rectangle which covers the whole page using pstricks and XeLaTex; for example

```
\documentclass[landscape,a0b,final]{a0poster}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-grad}

\begin{document}
  \psframe(0,0)(\textwidth,-\textheight)
\end{document}
```

This produces a cut-off rectangle with a4 width **not** landscape a0. If I change the document class option from landscape to portrait, it produces the rectangle correctly. However, in landscape mode it is missing the right side due to the image being cut-off at a4 width.

Doing a bit of a google, I found that the paper size needs to be set in the Ghostscript configuration file. So I used the command

```
kpsewhich -progname=dvipdfmx -format='other text files' dvipdfmx.cfg
```

to find the config file. Following advice online, I found the particular line:

```
D  "gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dEPSCrop -sPAPERSIZE=a0 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite  ..."
```

which shows that the paper size is being set to a0. Within the config file, there are some comments from the developers:

> In 2014, we discovered that -sPAPERSIZE=a0 was needed to support pstricks under xetex; otherwise, images were cropped (see thread at http://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2014-November/025664.html). Happily, it seems that using both -dEPSCROP and -sPAPERSIZE=a0 simultaneously works ok.  So that's we do below.

However, in my case, the `-sPAPERSIZE=a0` is not working. I tried editing the config file, changing from `gs` to `rungs` and this removed the rectangle entirely (there was also a comment from the developers in the config file, stating `rungs` is used as a wrapper). I also changed `-sPAPERSIZE=a0` to `-sDEFAULTPAPERSIZE=a0`, which did nothing.

Any help is greatly appreciated as I am totally baffled.

For reference, I am running Ubuntu 18.04 and Texlive 2017.

**Edit**: I just found a line in the config file, which includes a different config file called: `dvipdfmx-paper.cfg`. Inside that file is a single line

```
p a4
```

Oooh I thought!! However, changing this line to `p a0` did nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
\documentclass{a0poster}% has the same options as default
\usepackage{pstricks}

\xkoord=3370
\ykoord=2594 
\begin{document}
\psline(0,0)(\textwidth,-\textheight)
    \psframe(0,0)(\textwidth,-\textheight)
\end{document}
```

These values are written into the file `a0header.ps` which is later read by `xdvipdfmx`. But it has the wrong order for paperwidth/height.