# pstricks can't draw past a4 size on a beamerposter

Tags: pstricks, beamerposter

I'm making a poster using `beamerposter`; I would like to use `pstricks` to draw some figures on this poster. However, when I try to draw anything past about 2/3s of the poster width, nothing appears. Notice in the following that the vertical line is at x = 83 while the horizontal line ends at x = 90, but in the actual output, the horizontal line doesn't extend past the vertical line:
[image]

This was created with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{beamerposter}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\psset{linewidth=5pt} % Not necessary; just used for visibility

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{pspicture}
            \pcline{-}(0,0)(90,0)
            \pcline{-}(83,50)(83,-50) % Nothing gets drawn past x = 83
        \end{pspicture}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

(While not shown in the image above, text will appear correctly past x = 83.) Is there a way to fix this?

Edit:
This appears related to this issue I found: [pstricks image is cut to a4 in landscape mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469414/pstricks-image-is-cut-to-a4-in-landscape-mode)

However, the solution there doesn't compile for me since I'm not using `a0poster`.

Comment: Could you consider switching to Ti*k*Z?

Comment: I've done that for now, but I'd still like to figure out if there's a good way to do this for the future. The specific issue is that I'm drawing trees, and I'd like to use some of the fine-grained control that pst-jtree has that tikz and tikz-qtree don't.

Comment: For trees there is IMHO only one really good tool: `forest`. It is `tikz`-based and IMHO amazing.

Comment: Draw your picture with the `standalone` class, and insert the resulting .pdf via `\includegraphics`.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[dvips]{beamer}
```

will help

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/185956)

Comment: This _is_ the answer to the problem!

Comment: Sorry it is true that this comment is probably not the most appropriate for this situation. What I meant is mostly that giving a single line of code and saying it should help is not really a complete answer to any question. I think it would be better to add details and/or an example.